# How would the world be able to contain and/or destroy the Hulk? (MCU)

Tags: super-powers

In this scenario, the Hulk (MCU, not comic 616 Hulk) has been driven insane by unknown means and will rampage and kill until nothing is left. Banner's mind is gone leaving only an angry rampaging monster with no humanity. Destruction incarnate.

What are possibilities our world can do to contain and or destroy him?

For those unaware of this version of the Hulk I'm using and wish to understand his capabilities and feats, look here.

https://comicvine.gamespot.com/marvel-cinematic-universe/4015-56089/forums/mcu-hulk-respect-thread-2012952/

Comment: By "our world" you mean just the regular humanity or his fellow Avengers as well?

Comment: Not everyone on the site will not be familiar with the MCU specifics. Can you define specifics as to abilities and parameters. Say -  I've not seen Endgame for example, and am not familiar with Professor Hulk as portrayed, what are we looking at. (Also does this include the Lou Ferrringo years on TV?)

Comment: Who are you talking to, if you're not in someone's thread (as I am in yours) then you need to use the @"username" in order to ping them. (without the"")

Comment: I think that you've misunderstood me. If you were to address a comment to me then you would write @Chickens are not cows. I read your comment please re-read mine. We require questions here to be clear and well defined in themselves, if you refer to material outside the site - that's fine. but you need to make it perfectly clear what you are asking here and now - in writing. Voting to put on hold until the question is [edit]ed to be clear what it is asking.

Comment: Please describe in your own words in the body of the question what the link is supposed to tell us. Links get broken over time, we want the site to last for many years and broken links will make a nonsense of what you are asking.

Comment: @Chickensarenotcows I don't see how this question is vague or what's so confusing about it at all. I've provided material for others that aren't familiar with this Hulk and using a scenario of said Hulk attempting to destroy everything. What exactly is the issue here?

Comment: @Chickensarenotcows I read everything you said and you're not making sense to me. I added a respect thread which shows the abilities of this version of the Hulk. Are you asking me in particular to list them?

Comment: @Alexander Regular humanity. This world.

Comment: Yes I'm asking you to list them. Please re-write the question assuming all readers have no familiarity with the Marvel universe. When you ask how to trap the "Hulk" you need to tell us specifically what the "Hulk " is. This is a worldbuilding site not an MCU site or a movie site.

Comment: @Chickensarenotcows I'm fairly certain that those that read the material provided combined with the scenario listed is enough. I'm going to agree to disagree with you

Comment: It's not an issue up for chat, it's " A clear title. A reasonable explanation of what your question is. Add as much detail as you can. Any background research you've tried but wasn't enough to solve your problem." All as specified in the [help]. You offer us a problem that you have not clearly defined - "trap the MCU Hulk". This is not enough, please tell us what "Hulk" means. The "Hulk" has been failed to be trapped by the US military and many other forces, JB honest, the whole point of the "Hulk" is that it can't be trapped, it's a metaphor for avoiding growing up. What's your question?

Comment: I'm not sure this question is suitable for Worldbuilding, especially since it is using the MCU which is an already established universe. And it is about actions... perforingm a feat that has already occurred several times in the MCU itself. Ironman, Thor, Thanos, Dr Strange are all capable of defeating the Hulk in the Marvel Cinematic universe and the first 3 have been shown doing so.

Comment: @Shadowzee So you think this question is more suitable for another site? If so I apologize for the inconvenience.

Comment: @malikc6 You can try the Sci-Fi stackexchange. I believe they handle already established Universes. However, feel free to wait for further comments, clarifications or answers from other users of Worldbuilding.

Comment: Since this query is not about your own invented world, it really should be asked in a different stack.  WB.SE exists to help you create your own invented worlds, not answer questions about comix or movies or whatever.  [SF&F](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: **This would be extremely off-topic on SciFi.SE, please do not redirect OP there.** EDIT: Too late... OP already re-asked this there and it was hammered shut even before this one was. **Please do not redirect someone to another SE site without checking that their question is actually on-topic there.**

Answer (score 1):

**Blinding Lasers**

Blinding the Hulk is the start. It's much harder to destroy everyone if you can't see them. The military already has [lasers designed to blind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dazzler_(weapon)) the enemy.

You follow up with [sonic weapons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonic_weapon)

> Extremely high-power sound waves can disrupt or destroy the eardrums
>   of a target and cause severe pain or disorientation. This is usually
>   sufficient to incapacitate a person. Less powerful sound waves can
>   cause humans to experience nausea or discomfort. The use of these
>   frequencies to incapacitate persons has occurred both in anti-citizen
>   special operation and crowd control settings.

If the Hulk is blind and disorientated, his ability to destroy is severely limited.

Comment: Regeneration may prove this to be fruitless. Although from what I've seen in the movies of this Hulk, he doesn't seem to be able to regenerate limbs.

Comment: There is no reason why you need to stop the blinding and sonic weapons. You keep attacking